# How to get the Microsoft graph result in my console application?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

Currently, I am working in the console application(Visual Studio 2015) to get the group member detail (mail ID and name). For that, I searched lots to get the Microsoft Graphs output in my application. I found one [document](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/resources/samples/active-directory-dotnet-graphapi-console/) which says to register my app into the Azure portal. But I don`t wanna do this. I trying to achieve mine below idea.

I can able to get the desired output in the [Graph Explorer](https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/graph-explorer). If I use the same API URL in the browser means I get the below error.

```
{
"error": {
"code": "InvalidAuthenticationToken",
"message": "Bearer access token is empty.",
"innerError": {
"request-id": "823434fb-a2cc-44a7-9bb7-1249c02f54a5",
"date": "2017-02-24T09:45:05"
    }
  }
}
```

For example, If I use the below URL in Graph explorer input box means I get my desired output. But If I use the same URL in the browser`s URL box I get the error.

> https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/922345b-4sc6-443c-ac69-02bh73536570/members?$top=900&$select=id,displayName

Is that Graph explorer URL works in the normal browser or not?
If yes means How could I do it?

**Update**

I tried to get the output by using the below code

```
        string URL = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/922345b-4sc6-443c-ac69-02bh73536570/members?$top=900&$select=id,displayName";
        System.Net.Http.HttpClient client = new    System.Net.Http.HttpClient();
        client.BaseAddress = new System.Uri(URL);
        byte[] cred = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("mailid@domain.com:mypassword");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(cred));
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        HttpResponseMessage messge = client.GetAsync(URL).Result;
        string result = messge.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
```

But I got the below output in `string result`

```
{
"error": {
"code": "InvalidAuthenticationToken",
"message": "CompactToken parsing failed with error code: -2147184105",
"innerError": {
  "request-id": "8gd6720-d558-4bbd-a0b8-fd098gw30f0b",
  "date": "2017-02-24T11:03:34"
  }
 }
}
```

Is there any different way or Did made any mistake?

Answer (score 2):

You **must** to register the application in AAD and get a bearer token - the graph API doesn't support basic authentication, which is what your code is doing. The document you linked will walk you through the process.

Comment: I registered my account in AAD. But I don`t know how to access the groups by coding

Comment: Check out this sample: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-graphapi-console. Its a console app that connects to the graph to get data. Check out step 3 in the readme for adding an app registration to Azure AD